# Can we set special meta tags using an Xpages theme?

Tags: xpages

I'm aware that I can create ordinary `<meta>` tags using my Xpages theme. By "ordinary" I mean `<meta>` tags consisting of a "name" and a "content" attribute as in
`<meta name="author" content="me myself I">`.
What I don't know is how I could create different types of meta tags like `<meta http-equiv="expires" content="86400">` where we have a "http-equiv" attribute instead of a "name" one.
Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try this:

```
<theme>
    <resources>
        <metaData>
            <httpEquiv>expires</httpEquiv>
            <content>86400</content>
        </metaData>
    </resources>
</theme>
```

The generated HTML code looks like this:

```
<meta content="86400" http-equiv="expires">
```

Comment: Hm, that's what I thought and tried, but it didn't work. I'll try again, though

Comment: You're right (*of course!*); must have been a typo then upon my first attempt. Many thanks, again!

Comment: now I see what my typo was: the definition of the inner node is "<httpEquiv>" whereas I tried "<http-equiv>". Question is: where did you find that correct spelling?

Comment: @LotharMueller: In DDE XPage -> AllProperties -> Resources -> MetaData -> metaData[0]